# Subviews does not follow constraints and dismissing keyboard leaves a black space at the bottom of the view

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

Whenever my root view controller(Navigation Controller) pushes to my 2nd VC (let's call it VC2), all of VC2's subviews: buttons, labels, and text fields get shifted down even though I've set constraints on it. Also, whenever I dismiss the keyboard after editing the text field, the view goes back to its intended place where the constraints set it to be and leaves a black space at the bottom of the view. Here is my code for VC2:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: const.white)?.cgColor

    nameField.delegate = self
    emailField.delegate = self
    passField.delegate = self

    setUpTitles()
    setUpTextFields()
    setUpButton()

    addPaddingAndBorder(to: nameField)
    addPaddingAndBorder(to: emailField)
    addPaddingAndBorder(to: passField)


    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChangeView(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardIsDone(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChangeView(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)

}

@objc func keyboardWillChangeView(notification: Notification){
    view.frame.origin.y = -150 //This is temporary

}

@objc func keyboardIsDone(notification: Notification){
    view.frame.origin.y = 0

}

@objc func dismissKeyboard(_: UITapGestureRecognizer){ //Tapping outside the keyboard 
    nameField.resignFirstResponder()
    emailField.resignFirstResponder()
    passField.resignFirstResponder()

}

//Executed when hitting return key
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    nameField.resignFirstResponder()
    emailField.resignFirstResponder()
    passField.resignFirstResponder()

    view.frame.origin.y = 0

    return true

}
```

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Comment: (UI is built programmatically)

Comment: Can you add screenshots?

Comment: @ParthTamane It won't let me

Comment: How about Imgur links?

Comment: if you have added constraints try this code -> self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
If you have set frame and feel that is the issue .
try putting the frame code inside this ->
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.2) {
            <#code#>
  }

Comment: @ParthTamane [Before] (https://imgur.com/XNtX2sa)  [After] (https://imgur.com/2glut7K)

Comment: If possible can you share your code? It's easier that way.

Answer (score 0):

When you use responders you should make your first textfield to be a first responder, like that:

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        firstTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

[This is my answer in different issue](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/1559#issuecomment-576119575)